# Patching Strings with Ed Scripts

Tags: ruby

I'm using Ed scripts to track changes in a web app I'm developing. Ed scripts are probably the easiest kind of patch file for a computer to parse: [detailed explanation of Ed scripts](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Detailed-ed.html#Detailed-ed).

I quickly put together the Ruby code below with extremely little thought. I'd like to know what kind of high-level patterns I could use for a problem like this. I'm aware of state machines in an electrical engineering sense, but I'm not aware of the generally-accepted way to apply them in Ruby.

```
def self.apply_patch(old_text, patch)
  new_text_array = old_text.split("\n")
  patch_array = patch.split("\n")
  i=0
  current_line = 0
  while i < patch_array.length
    #grab the command
    patch_array[i].match(/(\d*),?(\d*)(\w)/)
    first_line = $1.to_i
    last_line = $2.to_i
    command = $3
    if first_line == 0
      first_line = current_line
    end
    if last_line == 0
      last_line = first_line
    end
    case command
    when "a"
      current_line = first_line
      i+=1
      while patch_array[i] != "."
        if patch_array[i] == ".."
          if patch_array[i+2] == "s/.//"
            new_text_array.insert(current_line, ".")
          else
            new_text_array.insert(current_line, "..")
          end
        else
          new_text_array.insert(current_line, patch_array[i])
        end
        current_line+=1
        i+=1
      end
    when "d"
      length = last_line - first_line
      for ii in 0..length
        new_text_array.delete_at(first_line-1)
      end
    when "c"
      length = last_line - first_line
      for ii in 0..length
        new_text_array.delete_at(first_line-1)
      end
      current_line = first_line-1
      i+=1
      while patch_array[i] != "."
        if patch_array[i] == ".."
          if patch_array[i+2] == "s/.//"
            new_text_array.insert(current_line, ".")
          else
            new_text_array.insert(current_line, "..")
          end
        else
          new_text_array.insert(current_line, patch_array[i])
        end
        current_line+=1
        i+=1
      end
    else
      if patch_array[i] == "s/.//" 
      else
        raise "invalid ed command"
      end
    end
    i+=1
  end
  new_text = new_text_array.join("\n")
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Strategy

The code would be more elegant if you made the `apply_patch` function more like a language interpreter.  Though it may be unavoidable that you have to treat the text as an array, you can treat the patch as a stream of instructions.  That would relieve you of the annoyance of having to increment `i`.

If your `patch` is already in string form, then you can turn it back into a stream using `StringIO`.  Chances are, you would be acquiring the patch from an input stream (such as `STDIN`), so you would use that stream directly instead.

To make that work, you would have to get rid of the `if patch_array[i+2] == "s/.//"` special case, which involves looking ahead by two lines.  In any case, you would be better off implementing support for `s/.//` as the string substitution command that it is meant to represent.

### Command parsing

This feels like a lot of lines of code to parse the command line, especially to handle the fallback line numbers:

> ```
> #grab the command
> patch_array[i].match(/(\d*),?(\d*)(\w)/)
> first_line = $1.to_i
> last_line = $2.to_i
> command = $3
> if first_line == 0
>   first_line = current_line
> end
> if last_line == 0
>   last_line = first_line
> end
> ```

You could simplify `first_line` and `last_line` by assigning the values correctly the first time.  To do that, you would need a regexp that produces a `nil` capture group when the number is missing.

For stricter validation, the regexp should be anchored by `\A` and `\Z`.  I suggest using a using the regexp to specify exactly what commands are supported, for validation.

If the command is unsupported, you should raise some kind of exception rather than raising a `String` object.  The exception message should include the bad command, to aid debugging.

### Text manipulation

The name `new_text_array` is a bit cumbersome.  How about just `text`?  You don't need to assign the result to a `new_text` variable at the end of the function.

Instead of deleting a line at a time using `delete_at`, you can knock out an entire slice at once, using a `Range` for array indexing.

There is code duplication between the `a` command and the `c` command.  The key insight is that a `c` (change) is just a combination of `d` (deletion) and `a` (append).

### Suggested solution

This is about half the original line count.

```
require 'stringio'

def self.apply_patch(old_text, patch)
  text = old_text.split("\n")
  patch = StringIO.new(patch)
  current_line = 1

  while patch_line = patch.gets
    # Grab the command
    m = %r{\A(?:(\d+))?(?:,(\d+))?([acd]|s/\.//)\Z}.match(patch_line)
    raise ArgumentError.new("Invalid ed command: #{patch_line.chomp}") if m.nil?
    first_line = (m[1] || current_line).to_i
    last_line = (m[2] || first_line).to_i
    command = m[3]

    case command
    when "s/.//"
      (first_line..last_line).each { |i| text[i - 1].sub!(/./, '') }
    else
      if ['d', 'c'].include?(command)
        text[first_line - 1 .. last_line - 1] = []
      end
      if ['a', 'c'].include?(command)
        current_line = first_line - 1
        while (patch_line = patch.gets) && patch_line.chomp! != '.'
          text.insert(current_line, patch_line)
          current_line += 1
        end
      end
    end
  end
  text.join("\n")
end
```

Comment: This solution is so readable _and_ clever :) @200_success I think the line `current_line = first_line - 1` should be `current_line = first_line - (command=='a' ? 0 : 1)` because Ed scripts are 0-indexed for adds, and 1-indexed for changes and deletions.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, a state machine is a good solution for this kind of text processing. It may be a bit more verbose, but IMO it's more clear than any custom solution.

In Ruby, you implement state machines using `reduce` with a state object that changes on every iteration. Ideally, you'd like to do it functionally (no in-place updates), but it would be slow for this kind of diff algorithms. So I'd just update the structures in-place when needed. I'd write:

```
def apply_patch(base_contents, patch_contents)
  initial_state = {key: :read_command, output: base_contents.each_line.to_a}

  patch_contents.each_line.reduce(initial_state) do |state, patch_line|
    unescaped_line = patch_line == "..\n" ? ".\n" : patch_line
    case state[:key]
    when :read_command
      regexp = /(?<nline>\d+)(?<cmd>a)|(?<start>\d+)(,(?<end>\d+))?(?<cmd>c|d)/
      match = patch_line.strip.match(regexp)
      case match[:cmd]
      when "a"
        state.merge(key: :in_add, nline: match[:nline].to_i, lines_to_add: [])
      when "c"
        range = (match[:start].to_i-1..(match[:end] || match[:start]).to_i-1)
        state.merge(key: :in_replace, range: range, lines_to_replace: [])
      when "d"
        range = (match[:start].to_i-1..(match[:end] || match[:start]).to_i-1)
        state[:output].slice!(range)
        state.merge(key: :read_command, output: state[:output])
      end
    when :in_add
      if patch_line == ".\n"
        state[:output][state[:nline]...state[:nline]] = state[:lines_to_add]
        state.merge(key: :read_command, output: state[:output])
      else
        state.merge(lines_to_add: state[:lines_to_add] << unescaped_line)
      end
    when :in_replace
      if patch_line == ".\n"
        state[:output][state[:range]] = state[:lines_to_replace]
        state.merge(key: :read_command, output: state[:output])
      else
        state.merge(lines_to_replace: state[:lines_to_replace] << unescaped_line)
      end
    end
  end[:output].join
end
```

Comment: Note that support for the exceptional `s` command still needs to be added — but that's not difficult.

Comment: Yes, I ignored it :p addin the helper function.

Comment: `chomp` needs to be applied more consistently to `patch_line`.

Comment: Despite these fixable problems, this does look like a nice solution.

Comment: `unescape` is the helper function to convert ".." to "." (code changed). I am sure it has still some bugs, but it works for some examples I tried, so I guess the chomps and the `...` are correct.

Comment: I see. That's a different way of handling`.`, and I think it should work.

Comment: How does this handle the case where a line is added that is just `..`?

Comment: @user24786: With the variable `unescaped_line`.